# Swift - Arrange Second Dictionary in Dictionary Alphabetically and by values

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have Dictionary of type:`Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Int64>>`

```
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementB"] = 8
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementC"] = 16
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementA"] = 32
```

I want to arrange my second dictionary alphabetically:

```
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementA"] = 32
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementB"] = 8
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementC"] = 16
```

And by value:

```
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementA"] = 32
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementC"] = 16
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementB"] = 8
```

I need func of type `arrangeAlphabetically(myDict:Dictionary<String, Int64>)->Dictionary<String, Int64>` and another one `arrangeByValue`.How it will be done?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered, so the answer is "it won't"  Perhaps you need to reconsider the question.

Comment: You will have to use an array if you need to preserve ordering. Your array could contain a series of *(key, value)* tuples or similar.

Comment: (Array(myDict).sorted {$0.0 < $1.0}) This sorted it alphabetically, but I can't sort it by values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dictionary` is essentially a unordered collection type. Meanwhile, it's a sequence of `(Key, Value)` pair tuples. You can get `sorted()` these tuples.

```
var myDict:[String:[String:Int64]] = ["DictA":[:]]

myDict["DictA"]!["ElementA"] = 32
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementC"] = 16
myDict["DictA"]!["ElementB"] = 8

let sortedByKeyAsc = sorted(myDict["DictA"]!) { $0.0 < $1.0 } // by keys ascending
let sortedByValDesc = sorted(myDict["DictA"]!) { $0.1 > $1.1 } // by values descending

println(sortedByKeyAsc) // -> [(ElementA, 32), (ElementB, 8), (ElementC, 16)]
println(sortedByValDesc) // -> [(ElementA, 32), (ElementC, 16), (ElementB, 8)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dictionary are by essence unordered** so in a few words : you cannot.

You could put your values in arrays in the order you need as array are ordered.